# allow just running of two specific programs (scripts) for user's account

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I don't have much experience with user privileges in Raspbian (Debian for Raspberry Pi). Sorry for "stupid" question but I would like to ask you for help with this. (I think it has something to do with privileges.)
My RPi is set to boot to default desktop environment (for default user "pi"). In LXDE I set auto run of my python script after start. Now, I would like to set for this user his account that way, so he will just have privilege for running my python script in /home/pi (or more my scripts I define). All other system functions should be "disabled" for user (I mean he should not be able to run other applications in Raspian or gain sudo access, or change system settings), so I want to prevent another program running via user click. (I hid all desktop icons and taskbar, too)

Comment: What will this be used for? What you're asking for isn't really possible, but your underlying goal could perhaps be met some other way. For a normal user, `sudo` isn't possible by default, so neither is changing the system settings, and you could perhaps give the user a home directory on a filesystem that's mounted noexec to prevent him from executing a file he wrote to, but stopping him from running anything in /usr/bin would require redoing *all* the permissions (they're all `a+x`) and then changing everything that depended on the previous permissions. [1/2]

Comment: However, given that your user doesn't know of any exploits, just not giving `sudo` access should be enough to prevent him from screwing the system up. And if you're trying to have a kiosk-like setup, there are programs available for that. [2/2]

Comment: thanks, I googled what is "kiosk-like" and yes, it looks it should be something like kiosk.